# Spreading out text vertically inside a parbox or minipage automatically

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

How can `TeX` (whether it is in its own terms or in those of `LaTeX2e`) be told to typeset the text spread out vertically and evenly inside a parbox or a minipage that has been defined with a given vertical size through the optional arguments of the `parbox` command or the `minipage` environment?

Please, consider that I'm talking about running text that is to be divided into vertical boxes (lines) automatically by `TeX`, as opposed to being broken into different lines manually by the author (in the latter case, I already know I could issue `\vfill` commands).

Pointing to a package that does this would be acceptable as an answer.

I  believe this question does not require an MWE, but if so required I'd provide one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this can answer your question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t][15cm][s]{.4\linewidth}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 50pt}
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\end{minipage}%
}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The `s` specifier tells the `minipage` to stretch the text vertically and the line

```
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 50pt}
```

adds much glue so the text can be stretched.

Comment: Yes, it does, even though my question is actually a duplicate, as it has already been pointed to, and I have myself voted to close it. Actually, egreg's answer to the linked question is more general in that it sets `plus 1fil` for glue. Nonetheless, I have marked yours as a valid answer.

Comment: @Marcos Neither I had seen it was a duplicate... I, too, have voted for closing it. Anyway, being this the first time you accept an answer of mine, I have to say thank you very much!