# Even vertical distribution of lines in a multiline cell

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing, makecell

I am trying to create a figure which has two or three photos on the right and text on the left. What I want is for the text on the left to be equally spread across the height of the cell (equal to the height of the photo). This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
              \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                        \makecell[cc]{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{example-image-a}\\ text below image A} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{example-image-b}\\ text below image b}\\
                        \makecell[cc]{line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \\} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{example-image-a}\\ text below image A} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.5 \textwidth]{example-image-b}\\ text below image b}\\
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{caption of the whole figure}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I tried using `\vfill` like this:

```
\makecell[cc]{\vfill line1 \\ \vfill line2 \\ \vfill line3\\}
```

but with that I get an error saying "Missing \endgroup inserted". Just using more `\\` between the lines seems very hacky to me.

What would be the best way to get equal amounts of space below, above and between the three lines of text on the left?

Comment: I can do it with \savebox and \parbox, but I would have to dig into the interstices of \makecell to achieve the same effect (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got the vertical spacing to work, by replacing all the '\makecells' with '\parbox' and adding '\vfill' in between the lines. With that change the vertical distribution looks perfect. 
The only problem I have is determining the width of the parboxes, since that is a non optional parameter. I would like the boxes to be as wide as the needed for the text. Also horizontal alignment gets rid off the vertical spacing. At the moment the text is on the left, but as soon as I add '\centering' or a flushright the vertical spacing is gone again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier to show than explain.  BTW, I also tried using `\\[\fill]` in `\makecell`, but no joy.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
           \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.4 \textwidth]{example-image-a}}%
           \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=0.4 \textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
              \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                \parbox[c][\dimexpr \ht0+\normalbaselineskip][s]{\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth - 6\tabcolsep}%
                  {\centering line 1 \\[\fill] line 2 \\[\fill] line 3 \\[\fill]} & 
                    \makecell[cc]{\usebox0 \\ text below image A} & 
                    \makecell[cc]{\usebox1 \\ text below image b}\\
                        \makecell[cc]{line 1 \\[\fill] line 2 \\[\fill] line 3 \\[\fill]} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.4 \textwidth]{example-image-a}\\ 
                        text below image A} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=0.4 \textwidth]{example-image-b}\\ text below image b}\\
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{caption of the whole figure}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

This version measures the width of the text in a throwaway tabular, then computes the width of the images to fill the remaining space.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\newlength{\tempdima}% \dimen0 doesn't work here

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
          \sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} line 1 \\ line 2 \\ line 3 \end{tabular}}% measure width of text
          \setlength{\tempdima}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 3\tabcolsep - 0.5\wd0}%
          \sbox1{\includegraphics[width=\tempdima]{example-image-a}}% measure height of image
          \sbox2{\includegraphics[width=\tempdima]{example-image-b}}% measure height of image
          \dimen1=\ht1
          \ifdim\ht2>\ht1 \dimen1=\ht2 \fi
          \advance\dimen1 by \arraystretch\baselineskip
          \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \parbox[c][\dimen1][s]{\wd0}%
              {\centering line 1 \\[\fill] line 2 \\[\fill] line 3 \\[\fill] \hrule} & 
                \makecell[cc]{\usebox1 \\ text below image A} & 
                \makecell[cc]{\usebox2 \\ text below image b}\\
            \makecell[cc]{line 1 \\[\fill] line 2 \\[\fill] line 3 \\[\fill]} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=\tempdima]{example-image-a}\\ 
              text below image A} & \makecell[cc]{\includegraphics[width=\tempdima]{example-image-b}\\ text below image b}\\
            \end{tabular}
          \caption{caption of the whole figure}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution is to use a `minipage` inside a `tabular` and adapt @karlkoeller ’s [answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156979/9632). In this revised example, the heights and widths are calculated to avoid overfull `hbox`es:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx, ragged2e, array, calc}

\newlength{\picheight} % height of picture, use same height on the minipage
\newlength{\cwidth} % calculate the width of columns, use same width for the picture

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\small\RaggedRight\small\hspace{0pt}}m{\textwidth-(2\cwidth+4\tabcolsep)}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\cwidth}}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\cwidth}{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth-2\tabcolsep]{example-image-a}}
\settototalheight{\picheight}{\includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{example-image-a}}

\begin{figure}

\begin{tabular}{@{}TPP@{}}

\begin{minipage}[b][\picheight][s]{\linewidth} % minipage has same height as the pictures
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 50pt}%
I am trying to create a figure or something nice to write.%
\end{minipage}
& \includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{example-image-a} 
& \includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{example-image-b}\\
& text below image A & text below image B \\
 \begin{minipage}[b][\picheight][s]{\linewidth}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 50pt}%
Here, I am trying to write some interesting words regarding a figure or something.%
\end{minipage}
& \includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{example-image-a} 
& \includegraphics[width=\cwidth]{example-image-b}\\
& text below image C & text below image D \\
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption of the whole figure}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]